Laravel 9 how to send current request object to the job dispatch
I have a job which will make xlsx exports. I made a crontroller where I call
public function index(Request $request): JsonResponse
{
    $userId = auth()->id();

    ExportCustomersJob::dispatch($request, $userId);

    return $this->sendJsonResponse();
}

I am using Redis for job queues but it seems the params from dispatch were not stored to the redis. All I see in redis is this.
{
    "uuid": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "displayName": "App\\Jobs\\Exports\\ExportCustomersJob",
    "job": "Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler@call",
    "maxTries": null,
    "maxExceptions": null,
    "failOnTimeout": false,
    "backoff": null,
    "timeout": null,
    "retryUntil": null,
    "data": {
        "commandName": "App\\Jobs\\Exports\\ExportCustomersJob",
        "command": "O:35:\"App\\Jobs\\Exports\\ExportCustomersJob\":0:{}"
    },
    "telescope_uuid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "tenant_id": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "attempts": 0,
    "type": "job",
    "tags": [],
    "silenced": false,
    "pushedAt": "1716289050.5038"
}

How can I send the current request to the queue? The request should contain filters for the query.
